# "X used to be Y"

Tags: past-tense

"X used to be Y" or "X was previously Y" both sound clunky to me, considering the present tense "X is Y" and the future tense "X will be Y".

- I find "used to" clunky because the word "used" generally wouldn't fit in that context (e.g. "A shovel is used to dig a hole").
- I find "was previously" too formal.

Is there a nicer expression that can be used in this circumstance?

Comment: Note that in speech *used to be* gets run together as "youstabee"

Comment: It needs to be understood why you find them clunky, in fact, how you define "clunky." The answer will depend on that.

Comment: Would "X, nee Y" be "nicer?" :)

Comment: If you find them too clunky, then deal with it? It's perfectly natural English and I don't think there is anything "nicer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for "X was once Y". In some contexts, even a simple "X was Y" would be cromulent.

But honestly, neither of your cited "clunky" examples is inappropriate - they're probably the two most commonly used constructions to convey the meaning you're after here. I'd just get over it.

Answer (score 1):

"X used to be Y" is really about the best you can do, because "used to" *strongly* implies that the case stated is is not the case anymore.

The pattern would suggest "X was Y" but, for reasons I don't fully understand, that sentence is just too short.  It almost seems like it's totally agnostic toward the current state of things, only concerned with what was the case before.  That is, it doesn't really say anything about how things are now.